# Show datalabels only if label value > 0

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have a question regarding ng2 charts.
This is my **component.ts** file.

```
public barChartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
    responsive: true,
    // We use these empty structures as placeholders for dynamic theming.
    scales: {
      x: {},
      y: {
        min: 10
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
      },
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'center',
        align: 'center'
      }
    }
  };
  public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
  public barChartPlugins = [
    DataLabelsPlugin
  ];

  public barChartData: ChartData<'bar'> = {
    labels: [ '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012' ],
    datasets: [
      { data: [ 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40 ], label: 'Series A' , stack: 'a',},
      { data: [ 28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90 ], label: 'Series B' , stack: 'a',},
      { data: [ 28, 48, 0, 19, 86, 27, 90 ], label: 'Series C', stack: 'a', },
      { data: [ 28, 0, 90, 79, 66, 7, 9 ], label: 'Series D', stack: 'a', },
    ]
  };

  public randomize(): void {
    // Only Change 3 values
    this.barChartData.datasets[0].data = [
      Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
      59,
      80,
      Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
      56,
      Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
      40 ];
  }
```

This is my **component.html** file

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div style="display: block">
      <canvas baseChart
        [data]="barChartData"
        [options]="barChartOptions"
        [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
        [type]="barChartType">
      </canvas>
    </div>
    <button mat-button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="randomize()">Update</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how it looks like
[ng2 chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB7ID.png)

I want, that the values only get displayed, if they are **not 0**
It works, if I set

```
datalabels: {
  anchor: 'end',
  align: 'end'
}
```

But I want to work as well, if I use center.

Thanks in advance

Cheers

David

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `formatter` function for this, if the value is bigger then 0 return it, else return an empty string:

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels)

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 0, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        color: 'red',
        formatter: (val) => (val > 0 ? val : '')
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
 datalabels: {
        anchor: 'center',
        align: 'center',
        display: function(context) {
          return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex]! >= 6; // or >= 1 or ...
        }
      }
```